# How to find all $B$ that commute with $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $$
        A=\left(\begin{matrix}
        \lambda_1 I_{n_1} &   &   \\
          & \ddots &   \\
          &   & \lambda_r I_{n_r} \\
        \end{matrix}\right) \in \mathbb F^{n\times n},
$$ where $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_r$ are distinct and $n_1 + \cdots+ n_r =n$. I'd like to find all $B\in \mathbb F^{n\times n}$ such that $AB=BA$.

I think the form $$
        B=\left(\begin{matrix}
        B_1 &   &   \\
          & \ddots &   \\
          &   & B_r \\
        \end{matrix}\right) \in \mathbb F^{n\times n}, 
$$ where $B_j \in \mathbb F^{n_r\times n_r} $ is a good candidate. Any matrix of this form clearly commutes with $A$. But how does one show the necessary condition?

I've tried assuming that one of the other entries is non-zero and was hoping to show that they wouldn't commute yet it doesn't seem to be the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Divide $B$ into blocks $B_{ij} \in \mathbb{F}^{n_i \times n_j}$ for $1 \le i,j \le r$.

Then, $AB = BA$ iff $(AB)_{ij} = (BA)_{ij}$ for all $1 \le i,j \le r$.

You can compute $(AB)_{ij} = \lambda_iB_{ij}$ and $(BA)_{ij} = \lambda_jB_{ij}$.

What does this tell you about the blocks of $B$?